# safe way to "encrypt" or lock created file for unauthorized user - Java

Tags: java, file, security

I am working on a own project to store my private passwords into a file.

But the biggest problem is that everyone can open this file.
I am looking for a method to **lock** or **encrypt** the data inside and maybe to decrypt only with the application in use.

The program takes 2 raw-Strings for username and password.
I know from a lot of sources and sites that storing raw Strings for password is one of the biggest leaks in programming.

Is there any safe way to avoid data theft from any virus and unauthorized users?

Comment: To do this securely, you need to encrypt the file, and decrypt it using a key that is stored securely, not on the computer. That key could be a strong password that you keep in your brain, or something on some secure hardware that you plug in and unlock with a simpler PIN. It's not clear what you mean by "byte streams". Everything on a computer is a sequence of bytes, even text. To make this safe, you have to use a cipher to encrypt those streams.

Comment: so it would be safe or lets say safer if I start the application with an awaiting PIN and after match grant access to the file, right?

Comment: Not just grant access, but use that information to decrypt the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Using password-based encryption on a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673556/using-password-based-encryption-on-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Securing passwords is not easy to get correct, use a well accepted password manager. Obligatory: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"