# Encrypting/Decrypting PKCS#7 files using passphrase

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key, pkcs#7, passphrase

Is it possible to encrypt a .p7b file using a passphrase. ? I need to support the encrypted PKCS#7 files and then later use the java code to decrypt it.

Comment: Every file can be encrypted and decrypted as byte arrays!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using password-based encryption on a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673556/using-password-based-encryption-on-a-file-in-java)

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3211

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in three steps:

1. Derive a key from your passphrase
2. Encrypt data with key
3. Package data into PKCS7/CMS format

**Step 1 - Key Derivation**

There are a few options for this. Some of the more common options are [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), and [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

**Steps 2 & 3 - Encryption & CMS Packaging**

Since you tagged this with Java, I recommend using Bouncy Castle's [CMSEncryptedDataGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSEncryptedDataGenerator.html) class to construct the CMS object.